# How to split a string in multiple part using first bracket in R?

Tags: r, string, split

I have strings like -

```
st1<- c("realme C20 (Cool Blue, 32 GB)")
st2<- c("realme C11 (2021) (Cool Grey, 2GB RAM, 32GB Storage)")
```

and I want to split s.t. I get my output as -

```
output1
[1] "realme C20"       "Cool Blue, 32 GB" "NA"
output2
[1] "realme C11"       "2021"             "Cool Grey, 2GB RAM, 32GB Storage"
```

I have no idea at all about how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regex is my weak point, but maybe this helps you:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)


str_split(st1,"\\(|\\)") %>% unlist()
[1] "realme C20 "      "Cool Blue, 32 GB" ""                

str_split(st2,"\\(|\\)") %>% unlist()
[1] "realme C11 "                      "2021"                            
[3] " "                                "Cool Grey, 2GB RAM, 32GB Storage"
[5] ""
```

If `""` do not matter, you can remove them also

Answer (score 0):

A base R option -

Remove the closing brackets (`)`) using `gsub` and split the string on opening brackets (`(`).

```
split_string <- function(st) {
  trimws(strsplit(gsub('\\)', '', st), '\\(')[[1]])  
}

split_string(st1)
#[1] "realme C20"       "Cool Blue, 32 GB"

split_string(st2)
#[1] "realme C11"  "2021"   "Cool Grey, 2GB RAM, 32GB Storage"
```